# Interpolate reciprocal function from a set of points

Tags: python, math, polynomials

Not sure whether to post this here or on Mathematics. Anyway my problem is that I have a set of points that describe a curve like the following

[image]

The points end abruptly at `x=18` and I want to impute how the curve will continue later on. I reckon that the curve descends in a `1/x` fashion after reaching the initial spike. However I would like to find the exact function that approximates best my points.

Moreover I would like to put an end to the curve, i.e. I want to see the curve if it reaches 0 at `x=36` or `48` or `60` and obtain the equation accordingly.

I tried to solve this problem by using the `numpy.Polynomial.fit` function but with no luck (I believe that this is because the `Polynomial.fit` will not impute a reciprocal function). The results I obtained were not satisfactory as shown by the following picture (second degree polynomial). You can see that the curves do not reach the 0 at the desired x (36, 48 and 60) and they also show an abrupt step at the beginning of the interpolation.
[image: second degree polynomials as computed by Polynomial.fit]

Is there a method to do so?

Comment: Try fitting to 1/y instead.

Comment: Have you tried `numpy.Polynomial.fit(X, 1/Y)` or `numpy.Polynomial.fit(1/X, Y)` instead of `numpy.Polynomial.fit(X, Y)`?

Comment: Also did you notice the outlier point at the beginning of your curve? You should probably remove it from the data before doing the interpolation.

Comment: To make your post suitable for stackoverflow, you could consider adding a reproducible block of code together with test data.

Answer (score 2):

If the curve is roughly `y=1/x`, take the logarithm in both axis, and fit a polynomial `log(y)=P(log(x))`, which should be close to a straight line.

Your curve also looks like `y[i]=c1*y[i-1]+c2*y[y-2]+...+cn*y[i-n]`, so you can make a cloud of points `(y[i], y[i-1], y[y-2], ..., y[i-n])`, and fit a multivariate polynomial to those points.